# Unable to hide textbox when radio button checked

Tags: html, asp.net, radio-button

I am trying to hide/show text box when radio button is checked/unchecked using ASP.net but i am unable to do it. Can anybody help me out with this? what i am doing due to which i am unable to achieve what i want to. 
Thats my asp code

```
protected void OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                lblCC.Visible = false;
                txt_cardnum.Visible = false;

        }

        protected void OnCheckChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCC.Visible = true;
            txt_cardnum.Visible = true;

        }
```

HTML

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonCC" runat="server" GroupName="PaymentMethod" Checked="true" CssClass="radio-inline" Text="Credit Card" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckChanged1" /> 
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonEP" runat="server" GroupName="PaymentMethod" Text="Easy Paisa" CssClass="radio-inline" OnCheckedChanged ="OnCheckChanged" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the AutoPostBack of both the radio controls to True ?

Answer (score -1):

may be this can help you

[Hide/Show JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922442/hide-show-jtextfield)